# How to use custom Dockerfile name in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I am using Jenkins to build and publish the docker image. However I need to use two docker file in one application just for my use case.

Requirement is can I build and published two different docker image from two different Docker file from one source, or i need to use custom file name like argument `*-f*` in docker command so that I can build two pipeline, in Jenkins?

By default Jenkins picks the file with `*Dockerfile*`

**`ex: docker build -t dockerfile -f Dockerfile-custom-name .`**

Comment: What do you mean by "two different docker image from two different Docker file from one source"?

Comment: i have two docker file, like dockerfile1 and dockerfile2 in the source

Answer (score 5):

```
def projectImage = docker.build("imageName:tag", "-f Dockerfile-custom-name .")
```

This way you can even add `--build-arg` or any other argument before the `-f`. It is important to have the `-f` and `.` at the end of the second parameter.

Here's the documentation for it:
[Builds test-image from the Dockerfile found at ./dockerfiles/test/Dockerfile.](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

---

Edit (answer to comments):

Yes, my first solution proposal works in a Jenkins pipeline.

This should also work: 
`sh '''docker build -t docker1-tag:latest us.gcr.io/project-name/docker1-tag:latest -f "Dockerfile1" .'''`

The only downside of this one, is that you don't have the image in a variable, so you cannot use the `run`, `withRun`, `push` and other methods.

In your specific case, I would build the image with the name/tag of `us.gcr.io/project-name/docker1-tag:latest`, so I can call the `push` method and the image will be pushed to the registry. To have the second tag, a separate `sh '''docker tag us.gcr.io/project-name/docker1-tag:latest docker1-tag:latest'''` call would suffice.

Comment: is this using Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: and   _sh '''docker build -t docker1-tag:latest us.gcr.io/project-name/docker1-tag:latest -f "Dockerfile1"  .'''_ wont this work?