# Jenkins-Pipeline: How to use multiple docker containers, each one being specified by a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple stages defined inside my `Jenkinsfile` (pipeline mode).

I would like to run one stage (the local build) inside one Docker container,
and some other stages (the cross-build) inside another Docker container.

However, I would also like the Docker containers to be specified by corresponding `Dockerfile`s instead of just by an image name, since I need some customisation in the respective containers.

The [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-multiple-containers) states that both these things are possible.

However, [it also states](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#dockerfile) that `Dockerfile` will always be used as the filename for the docker container specification.

How can I create two separate `Dockerfile`s and tell Jenkins to use one of them for one stage, and the other one for some other stage(s)?

From my understanding, the `Jenkinsfile` should look something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent None
    stages {
        stage('Local Build') {
            agent { dockerfile true }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
        stage('Cross-build') {
            agent { dockerfile true }   // <--- How do I specify *which*
                                        //      Dockerfile to use here?
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951383/how-to-use-custom-dockerfile-name-in-jenkins-pipeline) seems to be asking a somewhat similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following details to the `Dockerfile` agent. So you can simply use `filename` and `dir` options.

```
agent {
    // Equivalent to "docker build -f Dockerfile.build --build-arg version=1.0.2 ./build/
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile.build'
        dir 'build'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg version=1.0.2'
        args '-v /tmp:/tmp'
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. With the help of your answer I have also since discovered that these additional keywords are documented [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters).

In addition, although not documented in the aforementioned documentation, I found that you can also use the `reuseNode true` directive inside the `dockerfile` section, ensuring that the container will be run on the same build node as the other stages. Which is exactly what I needed - as that node contains the checked out working copy.